# Nicknames in Various Historical Cultures

Tags: historical-linguistics, comparative-linguistics, names

There are a variety of ways to form casual address terms.

Using family terms is common ('brother'), shortening/modifying a given name ('Teddy' from Theodore), or something based on the person's characteristics ('Shorty').

What idea do we have of what people did in the past?

I know a lot of our sources are official, and less likely to have informal names. But what info DO we have?

PS. General trends for a culture, or specific examples, are both appreciated.

PSS. I'm most interested in the Early Medieval/Post-Classic period - 500AD-1200ADish. And/or in the Americas, India, SE Asia, Eastern Africa, Japan, Ireland, and the Middle East. But any and all anecdotes/facts would be appreciated. Onomastics is fascinating.

Comment: For medieval nicknames, see the DMNES blog here: https://dmnes.wordpress.com/?s=nicknames

Comment: Here's one set from my grandmother's childhood. Turn of the 20th century Mennonites in southwest Ontario speaking Pennsylvania Dutch: **Haasa Peter** (Rabbit Peter), who caught rabbits for food, having learned it from his father who also bore the name; Schmutz Noah (Grease Noah), a blacksmith; Revva Amos (River Amos), who lived by the river; Stieffel Henry (Rubber Henry), "who wore rubber boots all the time, even when other people didn't". She says they were given these names not only because they were poor, but also because "their given names were too common" (Mennonites reuse names heavily).

Comment: Thanks to both of you! @jknappen, that might be able to help with Irish trends!

Comment: @Luke Sawczak, I married in to a Mennonite family here in Manitoba, and find this especially interesting.